# Lower bound on a function of the number of divisors?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am trying to lower bound the following function, $n \ge 3$ is a natural number:

$$l(n):=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)-\frac{1}{n}(\tau(n)\log(\tau(n))+(n-\tau(n))\log(n-\tau(n)))}$$

where $\tau(n)$ counts the number of divisors. Is this function exponential or polynomial in terms of $\log(n)$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo in the denominator which seems to be missing a closing parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: How did this come up? The divisor function grows more slowly than $n^\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, so the denominator is basically $n\log n$, and $l(n) \sim n^{-1}$.

Comment: On second thought, the answer might change depending on where the typo is that @cs89 noticed.

Comment: Clearly, User, you're going to need some estimates for $\tau(n)$ to answer your question. So, what bounds do you know about for $\tau(n)$?

Comment: @AnuragSahay I am trying to estimate some time complexity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not many. Only those written at Wikipedia.

Comment: OK. What bounds were those? Have you gotten anywhere, applying those bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to write a comment but got too long, not sure if correct or what you were looking for but hopefully is useful otherwise let me know and I will delete it.

What I did was to rewrite the denominator as follows
$\ln(n)-\frac{1}{n}(\tau(n)\ln(\tau(n))+(n-\tau(n))\ln(n-\tau(n)))\\
=\ln(2)+\ln(n/2)-((\tau(n)/n)\ln(\tau(n))+(1-\tau(n)/n)\ln(n-\tau(n)))\\
=\ln(2)+(\tau(n)/n)\ln(n/2)+(1-\tau(n)/n)\ln(n/2)+(\tau(n)/n)\ln(\frac{1}{\tau(n)})+(1-\tau(n)/n)\ln(\frac{1}{n-\tau(n)})\\
=\ln(2)+(\tau(n)/n)\ln(\frac{1/2}{\tau(n)/n})+(1-\tau(n)/n)\ln(\frac{1/2}{1-\tau(n)/n})\\
=\ln(2)+\sum_{i=1}^2 p_i\ln(q_i/p_i)\\
\leq\ln(2)
$

where the last inequality is because we have that $p_1=\tau(n)/n, p_2=1-\tau(n)/n,q_1=q_2=1/2$ then $\sum_{i=1}^2 p_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^2 q_i=1$ and we can apply [Gibbs inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality) $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac{q_i}{p_i} \leq 0\qquad (\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac{p_i}{q_i} \geq 0)$

Therefore we get that
$l(n):=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)-\frac{1}{n}(\tau(n)\log(\tau(n))+(n-\tau(n))\log(n-\tau(n)))}\geq\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$